# Android tests coverage is not pulled with failed tests

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, maven, jacoco

I have a project in Android with Maven with several integration tests.

With the following configuration in the pom:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>17</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <test>
                        <coverage>true</coverage>
                        <createReport>true</createReport>
                    </test>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pull-coverage</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>pull</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <pullSource>/data/data/com.package/files/coverage.ec</pullSource>
                            <pullDestination>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</pullDestination>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

When all the tests success, the coverage file is pulled OK and I can use it in Sonar. But, if one of the test fails, the coverage file is generated into the device, but the pull-coverage task is never executed and I cant get the report in my project.

I tried to execute the task android:pull in test failures; but I get the following message:

```
Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.0:pull (default-cli) on project xxxx: Execution default-cli of goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.0:pull failed: Required parameter android.pull.source has no value. Please supply with -Dandroid.pull.source=value on the command line or as property or plugin configuration in your pom or settings file.
```

My pullSource is defined in my pom.

How I can get the coverage report with maven if one of my test fails?

Comment: Facing the same problem. Is this perhaps based on the Quality Tools for Android project? How did you resolve this?